# How to find the editor for multi view controllers

Tags: xcode

I am very new to xcode, got stuck in finding the editor to modify the code when created multiple view controllers. Whenever I click on any of the view controllers, I only see same editor contents and cant move to the others for coding.

I searched the web and stackoverflow but could not find a clear guideline on how to manage the editors for multiple view contollers. I have attached a snapshot.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post.

You should add code or images directly, since link-addresses can change. It also makes it easier for the SO community to reproduce your query.

Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t “find” code. You create it.

When you drag a view controller into the storyboard, it has the default class of UIViewController. It is up to you to make a new code file where you subclass UIViewController, and then to go back to your storyboard and change the view controller to that subclass in the Identity inspector.

Comment: Thank you, I thought by copy paste everything comes along with the new view controller, just went back and fixed it.